# Most Efficient Way to Initialize Java Fields that are Objects?

Tags: java

Say I have a class like so:

```
public class ManyFields {
    public Object1 object1;
    public Object2 object2;
    public Object3 object3;
    // etc.
}
```

I want to make sure these fields are not null upon trying to do anything with a `ManyFields`object. So perhaps I'd have a validation method like so:

```
public Object ensureNotNull(Object o) {
   if (o.object1 != null) o.object1 = new Object1();
   // and so on and so forth
   return o;
}
```

Is there a better, but also **performant**, approach here? Rather than checking if each field is null individually? I did explore reflection like so:

```
for (Field f : fields) {
    try {
        if (f.get(c) == null) {
            f.set(c, f.getType().newInstance());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, I've read this reflection isn't the most performant-friendly approach to initializing fields. Any suggestions would help? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to ensure a consistent state from the point of creation of a `ManyFields`, then you should instantiate all fields in a constructor. That's what it's there for and you don't need the null-checks.

Comment: @QBrute, agreed. However, in this case, for a little more context, I'm accounting for the possibility that someone can send me this `ManyFields` object with null fields. Like they intentionally go off and manually nullify fields.

Comment: Checking if each field is null _is_ the most performant option.

Comment: [`Class.newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--) is *deprecated* since Java 9.

Comment: As well as initialising the fields in the constructor, you should make them `private`, and have setters for them.  The setters can check for a null argument, and throw an appropriate exception (or do something different like make a new object).  That way, nobody can _"... intentionally go off and manually nullify fields ..."_

Comment: Exactly. The *actual* problem is right here: `public Object1 object1`;.  Make them `private` and initialized, and control the setters, and your problem disappears.

Comment: Appreciate the response, guys. Here's some more context: This POJO can and should be null (per Product requirements). As well as its fields. Different teams downstream of us will send this POJO in some sort of event. Though highly unlikely, I want to handle a scenario where they send null fields w/o penalizing them. Thus, I have to validate the POJO upon receiving it.

This is not a case of having getters/setters as those are present as well. This is about validating this POJO after receiving it.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is the worst and slowest way to do almost anything.

What you want is to *encapsulate* your fields:  make them private, so your class has total control over how they get changed.

If there aren’t too many of them, you can make them all final and have the constructor set them:

```
public class Person {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;

    public Person(String firstName,
                  String lastName) {

        this.firstName = Objects.requireNonNull(firstName,
            "First name cannot be null.");
        this.lastName = Objects.requireNonNull(lastName,
            "Last name cannot be null.");
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

With this approach, it is completely impossible for outside code to set the fields to null values.¹  If a caller passes null, the constructor never completes, so there can never be an existing instance of Person which has a field with a null value.  Which means you can make a *written guarantee* that callers will never have to check if the values are null:

```
/**
 * Returns this user's first name.  This value will never be null.
 */
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

/**
 * Returns this user's last name.  This value will never be null.
 */
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
```

You can even take it a step farther, and validate the values beyond just checking for null:

```
public Person(String firstName,
              String lastName) {

    this.firstName = Objects.requireNonNull(firstName,
        "First name cannot be null.");
    this.lastName = Objects.requireNonNull(lastName,
        "Last name cannot be null.");

    if (firstName.isBlank()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("First name cannot be blank.");
    }
    if (lastName.isBlank()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Last name cannot be blank.");
    }
}
```

If you have many fields, you can just use get-methods and set-methods instead of setting everything in the constructor.  In that case, it is useful to initialize each field to a non-null value, so the class is able to make the same non-null guarantee as with the constructor approach:

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName = "(unknown)";
    private String lastName = "(unknown)";
    private String socialSecurityNumber = "000-00-0000";
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth = LocalDate.MAX;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String setFirstName(String name) {
        this.firstName = Objects.requireNonNull(name,
            "Name cannot be null.");
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String setLastName(String name) {
        this.lastName = Objects.requireNonNull(name,
            "Name cannot be null.");
    }

    public String getSocialSecurityNumber() {
        return socialSecurityNumber;
    }

    public void setSocialSecuityNumber(String num) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(num, "Argument cannot be null.");
        if (!num.matches("\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Argument must be in the format nnn-nn-nnnn.");
        }

        this.socialSecurityNumber = num;
    }

    public LocalDate getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(LocalDate date) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(date, "Date cannot be null.");

        int age = date.getYear() - LocalDate.now().getYear();
        if (age > 150) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Invalid date:  no one is more than 150 years old.");
        }
        if (age < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Invalid date:  cannot be born in the future.");
        }

        this.dateOfBirth = date;
    }
}
```

---

<sup>1. It is technically possible for outside code to use reflection’s `setAccessible` method to hack the private members of a class that is not in a module, unless a SecurityManager is installed.  However, people who hack into things in this manner should expect the class to break in unexpected ways, as they are essentially “voiding the warranty.”  Meaning, it’s bad and no one should do it, and in fact later versions of Java won’t let them do it.</sup>

Comment: Appreciate the response. I agree entirely with this approach in a traditional scenario. Perhaps I should have given more context:

This POJO can and should be null (per Product requirements). As well as its fields. Different teams downstream of us will send this POJO in some sort of event. Though highly unlikely, I want to handle a scenario where they send null fields w/o penalizing them. Thus, I have to validate the POJO upon receiving it.